# Find $x$ for $b\equiv ax \pmod{p}$ for big numbers $a$, $b$ and $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

How can the value $x$ be calculated, when $a$, $b$ and $p$ are given?

$$b\equiv ax  \pmod{p},$$
where $p$ is a big prime number, $a$ and $b$ are big numbers, that can be factorized.

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: i factorized a and b and calculated GDC for some samples, but I have no idea how to calculate x.

Comment: read up on the euclidean alogorithm.  There will exist $m,n$ so that $am + pn = 1$ (assuming $a$ is not a multiple of $p$).  Solve that then let $x = b*m$.  (So $a*b*m + p*b*n = b$).

Comment: If $p$ is prime, factorizing $a$ and $b$ is not useful.  Finding the [modular inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $a \bmod p$ is quick.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is a multiple of $p$ but $b$ is not there is no solution, of course.

So I'm assuming you mean $a,b$ are not mulitples of $p$.  As $p$ is prime, this means $\gcd(a,p)$ and $\gcd(b,p) = 1$

By Bezoit's identity there are integers $m,n$ so that $am + pn = 1$.

Solve for those using Euclid's algorithrm.

(Let $p = k_1a + r_1$ and then $a= k_2r + r_2$ and the $r= k_3r_2 + r_3$ etc. )

Then $x = b*m$ will yield.

$a(b*m) = (am)*b= (1-pn)*b \equiv b \mod p$.

That's it.

Example:

If $a=54; b=36; p= 2017$

$2017 = k*54 + r= 37*54 + 19$

$54 = 2*19 + 16$

$19 = 16 + 3$

$16 = 3*5 + 1$

$1 = 16- 3*5$

$= 19 - 3 - 3*5= 19 - 3*6$

$= 19 - (19 - 16)*6 = -5*19 + 6*16$

$= -5*19 + 6(54-2*19)$

$=-17*19 + 6*54$

$= -17(2017 - 37*54) + 6*54$

$= -17*2017 + 635*54$

So $36 \equiv 36*1 \equiv 36*635*54 = 22860*54 \equiv 673*54 \mod 2017$.

Answer (score 0):

You want $x\equiv b\cdot a^{-1}$. If you can factor $a$ and $b$, then this is the product of each factor of $b$ with the $\bmod p$ inverse of each factor of $a$. If $a$ and $b$ have any common factors, they will cancel.

Comment: You should multiply on the left and it becomes $x\equiv a^{-1}\cdot b$.

Comment: @Pippo, Why does order matter in a commutative ring?

Comment: It doesn’t matter, but I think it can perfect the answer.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. Math isn’t more “perfect” when you make meaningless distinctions.